# FLVPlayback.load results in all sound, no video

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to change the source of the FLVPlayback component on my stage with the load() method. When the new video loads I hear the audio playing but I see no video. Any idea what could be going on here?

The videos are rtmp streams from a Flash Media Server. The load command looks somethink like this...

```
flv1.load("rtmp://192.168.1.111/vod/test/01");
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when you change the video source in FLVPlayback it sets the video's _visible property to false... why? I have no idea...

This is my solution...

```
var LoadListenerObject:Object = new Object();
LoadListenerObject.ready = function() {
    _root.flv1['0']._visible = true;
    _root.flv1.play();
} 
_root.flv1.addEventListener("ready",LoadListenerObject);
_root.flv1.contentPath = "rtmp://192.168.1.111/vod/test/01";
```